# RabbitMQ Multi channels

Tags: php, rabbitmq, rabbitmq-exchange, librabbitmq

I have developed a PHP application using RabbitMQ and NodeJs.
Then i made a copy of that application on the same server.
The problem is that sending any message in any application, the other application is listining also, so i want every application to work on isolated channel.

Send.php

```
$channel = $connection->channel();
$channel->exchange_declare($job, 'fanout', false, false, false);
$msg = new AMQPMessage($jsonData, array( 'delivery_mode' => 2 ));
$channel->basic_publish($msg, $job);
```

Receive.php

```
$channel = $connection->channel();
$channel->exchange_declare($job, 'fanout', false, false, false);
list($queue_name,, ) = $channel->queue_declare("", false, false, true, false);
$channel->queue_bind($queue_name, $job);
```

Comment: Change the channel name I guess.

Comment: channels are logical object over a rabbit connection to communicate with RabbitMQ server. They are not `isolated`, btw the meaning you put behind isolated. You could change the queue name/exchange on the other application

Comment: I actually have alot of queues, i need one variable to distinguish each application

Comment: You could use separate virtual hosts for each application